# Intergrate facebook to my iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am developing an application in which I need to integrate Facebook in my app.
where I can us the like functionality of facebook into  my app, Any idea about how can I do this?

Comment: Please write in correct english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may go with the official [facebook tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)

Answer (score 1):

use [Facebook graph api](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this [iPhone Facebook Connect Tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/)